# Can you change the default color for selected text in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I haven't found an existing post about this so I'll give it a shot.

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the default highlight color for selected text? Right now, whenever I invoke `.SetFocus` on a field, Access "selects" the contents of the field. The color it uses is black, and makes the data very hard to see. Is there a way to change that color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access simply swaps the background and foreground color as its means of highlighting text in a text box.  As far as I know there is no way to change this behavior.

Obviously you can change the foreground and background colors themselves, but there is no separate "highlight" color that you can set independent of the foreground/background.

Comment: @user986706: I see you've asked a few questions here on StackOverflow, but have not yet accepted any answers.  If you want to continue receiving quality help you should upvote helpful answers and mark the ones that specifically solve your problem as "Accepted."  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't specificity for List Boxes I still think it is worth a note that List Boxes work slightly different (not sure why... maybe a different developer!) the selected row on a list box will **inverts** the colour of the background and foreground separately instead of swapping them.

For example if you had a light blue text on a white background normally the selected row would be a red text on a black background. The white inverts to black and the light blue inverts to red.

Or if you had

*Not sure which method I like better but it would be nice if they where the same! Makes UI's look a lot better when they are consistent throughout the form!*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem can be caused by using a transparent text box on a background that is the same or similar color (with contrasting-colored text). Make sure you have the text box back color set to a same/similar color as the background.

Basically, you need the text box back color to contrast with the text. When highlighted, the highlight will be a contrasting color to the text box background color.